# How to convert C# byte array of a file content to upload in SF Attachment

Tags: apex, integration, attachment

I'm calling an external C# API which return me a file, that file I need to attach under Attachment.
I tried some ways but not able to get the right approach, below is the sample response from the API.

```
{
  "$type":"System.Byte[], mscorlib",
  "$value":"JVBERi0xLjUNCMzIDgggUi9HUzUgMTAgMCBSPj4+Pi9Hcm91cYXJlbg=="
}
```

Can anyone point me out to find what is the right way to process the byte array and save the file under attachment object.

Comment: Looks like Base64. If it is you can just put the $value into the body of an attachment and it should work. Have you tried that? I tried converting it but the mime type is of a PDF while I think the string is to short to actually be a PDf

Comment: You're welcome, happy to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you see a string that is supposed to contain binary data ending in a `==` or `=` there is a *very* strong chance it is [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded. Those equals will be padding characters that result from 8 bit encoding to 6-bits per character.

You can easily convert a Base64 string to a [Blob](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_blob.htm#apex_methods_system_blob) in Apex using [`EncodingUtil.base64Decode(inputString)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_encodingUtil.htm#apex_System_EncodingUtil_base64Decode).

```
Blob b = EncodingUtil.base64Decode('JVBERi0xLjUNCMzIDgggUi9HUzUgMTAgMCBSPj4+Pi9Hcm91cYXJlbg==');

Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
attachment.ParentId = parentId; // Something you want to link the attachment to
attachment.Name = 'attachmentName';
attachment.Body = b;

insert(attachment);
```

Comment: Actually I know that part, the issue was with that particular content, after conversion when I check the PDF file, it was not rendering. That's why I thought it might be different encoding. I tried this again with some other files and it start working. sometimes we really do silly mistakes to rely or try same thing recurrently.